# Using PageControl in a CollectionViewCell on a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uipagecontrol

I'm trying to display a PageControl for images in a CollectionViewCell.

Everything seems to be working correctly - the number of pages is correct and even the print(currentPage) shows the correct index; however, the PageControl doesn't show the correct current page.

EncounterDetailViewController.swift

```
class EncounterDetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

// MARK: - Properties
var selectedEncounter: Encounter?
var currentPage = 0

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (selectedEncounter?.images.count)!
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imageCell", for: indexPath) as! EncounterCollectionViewCell

    cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: (selectedEncounter?.images[indexPath.row])!))
    cell.pageControl.numberOfPages = (selectedEncounter?.images.count)!
    cell.pageControl.currentPage = self.currentPage

    return cell
}

// MARK: - ScrollView Delegate Method
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
    self.currentPage = Int((scrollView.contentOffset.x + pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)
    print(currentPage)
}

}
```

EncounterCollectionViewCell.swift

```
class EncounterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

}
```

Comment: which page does the `pageControl` shows?

Comment: you have a `pageControl` but you are calculating `currentPage` based on the `collectionView` `contentOffset`. why?

Comment: I'm trying to change the pageControls currentPage based on each horizontal scroll.

Comment: do you have a `scrollView` inside your cells?

Comment: I believe so - the collection view cells scrolled horizontally.  I was able to solve the issue by connecting the page control to the ViewController instead.

Comment: @pmanning do you mind to share the solution how you solve it please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best practice way but I connected the pageControl inside of my EncounterDetailViewController instead of the cell.

```
class EncounterDetailViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    // MARK: - Properties
    var currentPage = 0

    // MARK: - View did load
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageControl.numberOfPages = (selectedEncounter?.images.count)!

    }

    // MARK: - ScrollView Delegate Method
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
    self.currentPage = Int((scrollView.contentOffset.x + pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth)
    self.pageControl.currentPage = self.currentPage
}
}
```